# How to output selected object properthy name to paragraph in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have three variables in my maincontroller, one for select person, one for genre associated with selected person name, and an array of objects with data. I bind the data together in select element enviroment, but now my goal is to output selected items in paragraph for further manipulation, i managed to output selected person but it appears in vertical aligment. Can someone show me how to output for example in my case let's say this, I select Chris and in my paragraph I want to get "Genre that Chris listen are Indie, Drumstep, Dubstep and Electro"

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope){
  $scope.selectedPerson = 0;
  $scope.selectedGenre = null;
  $scope.people = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Leon', music: [ 'Rock', 'Metal', 'Dubstep', 'Electro' ] },
    { id: 1, name: 'Chris', music: [ 'Indie', 'Drumstep', 'Dubstep', 'Electro' ] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Harry', music: [ 'Rock', 'Metal', 'Thrash Metal', 'Heavy Metal' ] },
    { id: 3, name: 'Allyce', music: [ 'Pop', 'RnB', 'Hip Hop' ] }
  ];
});
```

HTML Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='app.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='maincontroller.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='content' ng-app='myAng' ng-controller='mainController'>
        <select ng-model='selectedPerson' ng-options='list.name for list in people'></select>
        <select ng-model='selectedGenre'>
            <option ng-repeat='genre in people[selectedPerson.id].music'>{{genre}}</option>
        </select>
        <p ng-model='people' ng-repeat='person in people[selectedPerson.id].name'>{{person}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please don't use angular for angularJs questions

Answer (score 1):

> i managed to output selected person but it appears in vertical aligment.

You run `ng-repeat` directive on single String. this is a reason why you get something like:

```
C

h

r

i

s
```

Maybe something like:

```
<p>Genre that {{people[selectedPerson.id].name}} listen are  {{people[selectedPerson.id].music.join(', ')}}<p>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Err074d23ZXBbp7sq5nK?p=preview)</kbd>

---

```
      <select ng-model='selectedPerson' ng-options='list as list.name  for list in people'>
        <option value="">-- Select Person --</option>
      </select>


        <select ng-model='selectedGenre'>
            <option ng-repeat='genre in people[selectedPerson.id].music'>{{genre}}</option>
        </select>


        <p>Genre that {{people[selectedPerson.id].name}} listen are  {{people[selectedPerson.id].music.join(', ')}}<p>
```

Comment: I am geting one paragraph for each item in an music array

Comment: @MarkoC can u explain?

Comment: No, that was earlier when I changed .name to .music on ng-repeat, now it's working with this example of yours.